# Giving Daan from money earned through Trading in Stock Market?

Tags: vedas, puranas, karma, practice, charity

I am currently trading in Stock Market Options. Its a sort of gambling where I earn small money through my predictions. As u know its legal as per my country law and am not hurting any one specifically.  If I loose I will feel bad for myself and not cursing anyone for such losses. Now My question is whether I can use the money earned through such platform for giving **Daan (charity)**.  ?

Comment: This is personal opinion. First of all trading stocks is not gamblimg, its legitimate form of business where you hold equity of actual compaines. Its like you are investing in companies. Of share market is gambling then all companies and banks are aids to gambling. It just can habe gains and losses like gamblimg but in itself is not gambling. Also I personally think even the money got from gambling can be used to give donation or charity, its possibly the best use of money.

Comment: Giving something in Charity is Important in not only in Hinduism but in  all major religions. In religious matters it's mandatory that you should earn the money in righteous or dharmic way. If your earned money falls in that category then there is no problem. I am voting to close this question as person advice question.

Comment: This is important question to be clarified. How is stock system seen from eyes of shastras?

Comment: @sbh - No matter how the question is important to one or more users it should fit within community rules/ guidelines. Some good question also needed to be closed for maintaining quality of the site. There are thousands of such professions , one can ask N no. of such questions.

Comment: I think it's chicken and egg problem. Without asking question, how can we know the answer doesn't exist? None of us can claim to have known all shashtras. If there is an equivalent of Stock business in old books (maybe Arthashastra?) then shouldn't this be attempted? Thank you.

Comment: No this problem doesn't arise. There is always scope to edit question and to make it fit for  community guidelines. The above post is both opinion based and personal advice question.

Comment: Thank u all for ur suggestion.  I tried through others sources also, but couldnt get perfect answer.  For this question I have three views which one is corrrect is left to lord.

Comment: First, Its legal as per my country law, its not a game of dice wherein I am hurting or snatcning from others, I feel guilty of my mistake & not cursing others.  Second, As per shastras it is void to use this for daan since it is not earned with hard work. Just ur are testing ur luck. And third view is that practice of rules mentioned in shastras may vary from time to time and place to place. (Ex. Many of us are having normal bath.  But shastras recomend ritualistic bath which only few are following)